# Is there a way to include material color changes in motion blur?

Tags: materials, keyframes, color, motion-blur

In both Eevee and Cycles, changes to the material color are not rendering in the motion blur.

For example, if there is a moving cube that is red on frame 1, and keyframed to transition to blue on frame 2, the sub-frame calculations do not result in a blur that trails off into purple. Instead the blur is *entirely* red on the frame that is keyframed to red, and *entirely* blue on the frame that is keyframed to blue.

I guess this is probably done to speed up rendering, but for my project that has quick color changes it is undesirable. Is there any way to get Blender's motion blur to account for material color changes as well as motion?

Comment: I'm not sure about the technical implementations, but I think the motion blur is calculated via speed vectors, and the color change simply doesn't generate speed vectors in the mesh... But I maybe completely wrong here.

Comment: The obvious answer is to render at a higher framerate, and then use video editing software (even Blender) to merge it back. I don't know how optical flow algorithm would deal with color changes, but simple alpha overlaying would get you exactly what you want.